# Send user to data usage settings window

Tags: android, settings, android-5.0-lollipop

Till android 5, user could turn on cellular data from the roaming settings window.
So Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS is used to send user there.

In lollipop though, you no longer can do that and the option to turn on mobile data is under data usage window. Question is, how can send user to that window as Settings don't seem to have anything to help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is currently a way to show programmatically the Settings - Data Usage screen on Lollipop 5.0.

The class [android.provider.Settings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) contains all possible values for Intent actions.

I tried all of these values by they did not lead to Data Usage:

- ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS
- ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS
- ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS

As a a fallback you can either show the generic Settings screen (ACTION_SETTINGS) or show a Toast notification telling the user to enable the Mobile Data Network.

Answer (score 2):

While there is no direct action available, you can launch the data usage activity directly. Here is how it works

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
                            "com.android.settings",
                            "com.android.settings.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity"));
```