# Android data turning on android data settings on button click

Tags: java, android

I have an app that does a check if data services is turned on and if it is not turned let display and alert dialog demanding the user to turn the app on clicking ok. This is my code that is supposed to show the settings of the android phone

```
final  Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
                          intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                           final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.phone","com.android.phone.Settings");
                          intent.setComponent(cn);
                          intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                          startActivity(intent);
```

The above code does not display the option to turn on the wifi of the user

Please why the wifi data not turned on, on clicking the button

Comment: huge topic, but I think very important to read that thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539445/the-setmobiledataenabled-method-is-no-longer-callable-as-of-android-l-and-later

Comment: Are you saying that nothing is wrong with my code

Comment: The thread points out that this is not possible, only on rooted devices.

Comment: Can I edit my question to include where I am trying to display the settings for the user to turn it on

Comment: sure you can edit your question. You can call the device settings screen to turn on/off mobile data, that´s allowed. But you can´t do it by yourself...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I have editted my question

Comment: then, maybe this could help. Try the second answer, I haven´t tested it, but it´s maybe a possibility....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27859457/send-user-to-data-usage-settings-window

Comment: On clicking nothing happens

Comment: have You made a log or a toast to be sure the click event itself is fired?

Comment: Yes it is if not the dialog itself will not even get ffired

Answer (score 0):

To enable the option to allow the user to turn on data services such wifi and others.

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Just call the generic Settings screen (ACTION_SETTINGS)

Reference link  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html

That will do the trick